# Set dots size of dotted_chart() in combination with ggplotly()

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly, bupar

Is there a way to reduce the size of the dots created with bupaR::dotted_chart() in combination with `ggplotly()`

```
library(bupaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(edeaR)
library(plotly)

ggplotly(dotted_chart(patients))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `plotly_build` to modify the `marker$size` per line like this:

```r
library(bupaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(edeaR)
library(plotly)

p <- dotted_chart(patients)

q <- plotly_build(p)
q$x$data[[1]]$marker$size <- 1
q$x$data[[2]]$marker$size <- 1
q$x$data[[3]]$marker$size <- 1
q$x$data[[4]]$marker$size <- 1
q$x$data[[5]]$marker$size <- 1
q$x$data[[6]]$marker$size <- 1
q$x$data[[7]]$marker$size <- 1

q
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>